# Is it possible to rgrep *.el.gz files?

Tags: rgrep

I often find myself debugging some stuff in the installed Emacs
sources, which are in `*.el.gz` form.  And the ability to `rgrep`
would be quite handy. Is this readily possible?

Comment: [ag](https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher) is a grep-like tool that uses [libarchive](http://www.libarchive.org/) for fast search inside compressed files whenever possible.  The `-z` switch enables that behaviour and has a good deal more performance compared to `zgrep`, especially when used in combination with a package like `helm` on many small files.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use the command `zrgrep`, which was introduced in Emacs 23.2.